# How to swap two rows of a Pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I have this dataframe :

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
1   5   6   7   8   9
2  10  11  12  13  14
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24
```

I want to swap the position of  row 1 and 2.

Is there a native Pandas function that can do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware there is no Native Pandas function for this.

But here is a custom function:

```
# Input
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(25).reshape(5, -1))

# Output
def swap_rows(df, i1, i2):
    a, b = df.iloc[i1, :].copy(), df.iloc[i2, :].copy()
    df.iloc[i1, :], df.iloc[i2, :] = b, a
    return df

print(swap_rows(df, 1, 2))
```

Output:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
1  10  11  12  13  14
2   5   6   7   8   9
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

Use `rename` with a custom dict and `sort_index`

```
d = {1: 2, 2: 1}
df_final = df.rename(d).sort_index()

Out[27]:
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
1  10  11  12  13  14
2   5   6   7   8   9
3  15  16  17  18  19
4  20  21  22  23  24
```

Answer (score 0):

Try numpy [flip](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.flip.html#numpy.flip):

```
df.iloc[1:3] = np.flip(df.to_numpy()[1:3], axis=0)

df

        0   1   2   3   4
    0   0   1   2   3   4
    1   10  11  12  13  14
    2   5   6   7   8   9
    3   15  16  17  18  19
    4   20  21  22  23  24
```

Answer (score 0):

```
df1=df.copy()
df1.iloc[1,:],df1.iloc[2,:]=df.iloc[2,:],df.iloc[1,:]
df1
```

[image]