# moving last two dataframe rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I'm trying to move the last two rows up:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A" : [1,2,3,4],
    "C": [5, 6, 7, 8],
    "D": [9, 10, 11, 12],
    "E": [13, 14, 15, 16],
})

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   A  C   D   E
0  1  5   9  13
1  2  6  10  14
2  3  7  11  15
3  4  8  12  16
```

Desired output:

```
   A  C   D   E
0  3  7  11  15
1  4  8  12  16
2  1  5   9  13
3  2  6  10  14
```

I was able to move the last row using

```
df = df.reindex(np.roll(df.index, shift=1))
```

But can't get the second to last row to move as well. Any advice what's the most efficient way to do this without creating a copy of the dataframe?

Answer (score 0):

Using your code, you can just change the roll's shift value.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "A" : [1,2,3,4],
    "C": [5, 6, 7, 8],
    "D": [9, 10, 11, 12],
    "E": [13, 14, 15, 16],
})

df = df.reindex(np.roll(df.index, shift=2), copy=False)
df.reset_index(inplace=True, drop=True)

print(df)

   A  C   D   E
0  3  7  11  15
1  4  8  12  16
2  1  5   9  13
3  2  6  10  14
```

The `shift` value will change how many rows are affected by the `roll`, and afterwards we just reset the index of the dataframe so that it goes back to `0,1,2,3`.

Based on the comment of wanting to swap indexes 0 and 1 around, we can use an answer in @CatalinaChou's link to do that. I am choosing to do it after using the roll so as to only have to contend with indexes 0 and 1 after it's been shifted.

```
# continuing from where the last code fence ends
swap_indexes = {1: 0, 0: 1}
df.rename(swap_indexes, inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

print(df)

   A  C   D   E
0  4  8  12  16
1  3  7  11  15
2  1  5   9  13
3  2  6  10  14
```

A notable difference is the use of `inplace=True` and thus not being able to chain the methods, but this would be to fulfil not copying the dataframe at all (or as much as possible, I'm not sure if `df.reindex` will make an internal copy with `copy=False`).

Comment: what if we want to flip row 1 with row 0?

Comment: You can refer to [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63423089/how-to-swap-two-rows-of-a-pandas-dataframe) posted by @CatalinaChou if you're looking to simply swap the rows around. You can combine it with using roll so that you will always only need to swap indexes 0 and 1. I'll edit an adapted version.